# What is the relationship between costmap config and URDF limits

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the relationship between costmap footprint and URDF model collision definition.  Other values like joint velocity and effort limits in URDF and limits in move-base config file how is the relationship to be view. Is the URDF the limiting factor or does move base over ride? I found some information here:
https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/wiki/joint_limits_interface
I am guessing that URDF specifications limits and footprint take precidence and anything set in move-base should be aliened with those setting.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80791/what-is-the-relationship-between-costmap-config-and-urdf-limits/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Someone might correct me, but my best guess for default move_base is: They are totally independent.

In other words: Both must be setup correctly, matching one each other. In particular move_base doesn't assume the robot configuration to change, i.e. the footprint is constant.

There are some move_base planner implementations that actually take the 3D environment and robot configuration into account.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0